# How can I get a page to redirect to another URL based on a GET statement inside the link?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am looking for a simple code that will forward the user to another URL specified in the URL:

Example:

http://example.com/index.php?URL=anothersite

the user lands on http://example.com/index.php and after 5 seconds is forwarded to anothersite

can someone help me out?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Redirect-a-URL

Comment: Not what I needed but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The JS example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var pair = (window.location.search.split("&")[0] || "").split("=");
   if( (pair[0] || "").toUpperCase() != "?URL") return;
   window.location = pair[1];
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the redirect target in the querystring, then use javascript to redirect!

URL: `http://example.com/index.php?URL=anothersite`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
             setTimeout(function() {
                 var match = /[\?&]url=([^&]*)/.exec(location.search);
                 if(match && match[1]) location.replace(match[1]);
             }, 5000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

The above example is for pure html, but if you can use php, that'll be more convenient to get the querystring parameter by `$_GET['url']`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
             setTimeout(function() {
                 location.replace('<?=$_GET['URL']?>');
             }, 5000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesnt redirect me :(